# Image sharing in Node JS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, backend, file-handling

**( I am new in Node js )**

I have just created a simple chat service where the client can send images to other clients , but
the process is very slow and the URL of the images is too long ...
this is my code, what I am looking for is a different way to send the image URL to the server which it will then send to the other clients.

---

Client-Side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="img" onchange="getImgSrc()" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit" onclick="submitImg()">
  <div></div> <!-- OUTPUT DIV -->
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    
    const socket=io.connect('http://localhost:80');
    
    var imgFile,fr,src,img;

    getImgSrc = () => {
      imgFile = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
      fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = () => {src = fr.result;} //Get Img Src
      fr.readAsDataURL(imgFile);
    }

    submitImg = () => {
      socket.emit('submitImg',src);
    }
    
    setImgSize = (img, width, height) => {
      img.width = width;
      img.height = height;
    }
    
    socket.on('sendImg',(src)=>{   // Create Img...
      img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = src;
      setImgSize(img, 200, 200);
      document.querySelector('div').append(img);
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Server-Side:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
app.use(express.static('client'));//index.html folder
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('submitImg',(src)=>{//Client submit an image
    io.emit('sendImg',src);  //the server send the image src to all clients
  });
});

const port = 80;
http.listen(port, () => {console.log('Server Running on Port ' + port)});
```

Thank you very much and hope you can help me.

Comment: it won't be instant no matter what you do, but if you use readAsArrayBuffer and add a 100kb image it's going to send 100kb if you use readAsDataURL it's going to send 133kb, because of the nature of base64.. but the initial part of the data uri includes the mimetype, which otherwise would need to handle yourself as part of the socket.io payload (or do in response which would need sharp or some other lib to look at the data). If you want to use readAsArrayBuffer, your need to Blob the response and make a data url. example https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-dawn-294m6 (notice its still slow)

Comment: Another possible improvement is to draw the image to an offscreen canvas, export the canvas image data as a jpg blob, get the buffer, then send _that_ buffer through the server. Before doing any of that though, just send a socket.io event at the beginning so the recipient can display some sort of loader while waiting for the image data to arrive briefly after.

Comment: You don't need to buffer anything. Ideally you would stream the image file as binary data, I'm not sure how to do that with socket.io or if it's even possible. You could send the file to your server in a POST request, using `multipart/form-data` is common for this. On the server you can stream the image file to disk (using fs streaming apis) then broadcast to clients a URL they can use as the `<img>` src.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you , your answer helped me a lot

Comment: @JakeHolzinger in my case I can't use this method.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts 
thank you very much, would you have a link please?